# Upgrading VS2015 to asp.net 5 beta7 I get Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I have upgraded DNX using the instructions on https://github.com/aspnet/Home I also downloaded DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi for visual studio 2015 but when I create a new project and run the website I get the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When I try to run the website from dnx command line I get the following

C:\code> dnx web
stem.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment' has been reg
tered.
 at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Ty
 serviceType)
 at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)

at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)
- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider service
ovider)
 at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
 at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider service
ovider)
 at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
 at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
 at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)

Comment: Can you check the versions in the project.json file?

Comment: I had to delete my project.lock.json file to get things working.

Comment: I think you didn't install tooling. You need to install WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like beta7 doesn't carry the **dnx.clr.managed.dll** anymore (and its dependencies). I've solved this problem with the following steps:

You can check if your *global.json* file is expecting beta7 by looking for the following node in *global.json*:

```
"sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta7",
        "runtime": "clr",
        "architecture": "x86"
    }
```

If your project keeps looking for the *dnx.clr.managed.dll* (and its dependencies), you can manually edit your *project.json* file (which stores the dependencies and replaces the old *cs.proj* and *vb.proj* files), to point to the expected dnx runtime version, for example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5"
  },
```

is edited to:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7"
  },
```

After saving the changes, you have to **restore** the dependencies. One way is to navigate with terminal (CMD) to the *ProjectName/src/ProjectName/* folder (where the *project.json* file is located), and execute the

```
dnu restore
```

command. Hopefully it will request the new dependencies successfully, and you are ready to go.

PS.: I didn't try to run with x64 setup, since free/shared apps might(?) not be compatible with 64 bit platform setup. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error after upgrading a project from beta-5 to beta-8 when trying to run it in IIS Express. I was able to fix it by removing this line in `wwwroot\web.config`:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

It must have been included in earlier versions of the project template and is presumably incompatible with the new request pipeline, but I haven't been able to find any documentation confirming this.