# Cannot run ASP.net 5 projects on VS 2015, both IIS Express and web

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I just installed VS 2015 Community without any errors.

When I create any of the ASP.net 5 web templates, the references node has the warning icon on it, and so do its child nodes DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0. The app won't build.

I saw somewhere that running `dnu restore` on the Package Manager Console will do the trick. Well, the warning icons go away and the app will build. However, when I run it, I get 'Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies.' on IIS Express and 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll' on web.

I tried repairing the VS 2015 installation, rebooted, and I still have the same problem.

Something might be incorrectly set up in my machine or installation. I don't think I should be running `dnu restore` every time I create a new project off a template (which won't actually run anyway).

I also have VS 2013 Community installed, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: did you install the latest beta7 tooling? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738

Comment: Didn't know that was necessary. I just ran the installer today, so I assume it would grab the latest everything. I'll try this, and get back to StackOverflow later.

Comment: be sure and create a new project after installing the new tooling, it should work.

Comment: Since it builds, try `dnu publish --runtime dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7`, which will publish not only your code, but also the runtime. You'll get `.bat` files named exactly as your commands in `project.json`. Running this, will run it self-hosted. You can then also point IIS to the wwwroot, which should run it hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The error regarding `dnx.clr.managed` in IIS Express may be caused by an obsolete HTTP handler registration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33894751/3248302).